# Bloquear Form por inactividad C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms que se logea con user y pass, la cual necesito que a un determinado lapso de tiempo sin usar (inactividad) el programa me pida nuevamente la contraseña.

Actualmente lo tengo inplementado de la siguiente manera.

Tengo un timer que cuenta los minutos, al llegar al tiempo determinado lanza nuevamente el form de login.
En cada uno de los controles del form en su evento de Mouse_Move tengo inicializado el contador del timer, para que mientras se este moviendo el mouse por los controles no aumente el timer.

Aunque este método me funciona como lo necesito; ¿existe alguna otra forma de realizar este procedimiento? digamos mas eficiente, ya que si mi FORM tuviera 100 controles, necesitaría 100 inicializaciones del contador, y se extiende el codigo.

Comment: Deberías crear una clase `FormBase` del cual todos tus forms hereden, y en ese form base creas el timer. En ese mismo form te suscribes a los eventos `MouseMove` y `KeyDown` y reseteas el timer cada vez que esos eventos se disparen. Finalmente, en el método de creación del timer, cuando llegue a los 30 minutos, le das log out al user. [Tal vez esto te ayude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603374/how-can-i-trigger-an-auto-logout-within-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: OK, no tengo conocimiento de todos los recursos que se usan en C#, tendría que reforzar esos conceptos que mencionas. Ya que si logro entender un poco lo que se trata de explicar, pero me falta un poco entender como llevarlo a la practica